# String replace with regex, ie strange results

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Why i have this results?

```js
"hello world".replace(/[']/gi, "\\'"); // on chrome => "hello world"
"hello world".replace(/[']/gi, "\\'"); // on ie => "hello world"

"hello world".replace((/[']/gi).compile(), "\\'"); // on chrome => "hello world"
"hello world".replace((/[']/gi).compile(), "\\'"); // on ie => "\'hello world"
```

Chrome: 43.0.2357.124 m

IE: 11.0.10011.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misusing the [`compile` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/compile).

> **Warning**: The `compile` method is **deprecated**, you shouldn't use it. Create a new `RegExp` object instead.

It's prototype reads:

```
regexObj.compile(pattern, flags)
```

So you have to pass it a new pattern that will replace the instance's pattern.

- Under IE, calling `compile()` yields the regex `/(?:)/` which is an empty regex that matches the empty string at the start of `"hello world"`. There's no `g` flag either, so you end up with `\'` prepended to the string.
- Under Chrome, `compile()` returns `undefined`, so no replacement is made.